# unable to call a thread in dll file

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

I am trying to create a dll which will create a thread when you load him
for some reason the thread function is not doing anything.. :\

this is my code:

dllthread != null.. why its not working?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(
  __in  LPVOID lpParameter
)
{

    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:    
        DWORD DllThreadID;
        HANDLE DllThread; //thread's handle

        DllThread=CreateThread(NULL,0,&ThreadProc,0,0,&DllThreadID);
// 
        if (DllThread == NULL)
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Error", L"Error", MB_OK);

        CloseHandle(DllThread);
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:


        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Creating a thread from DllMain is a [bad idea](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/09/04/4731478.aspx).

Comment: what are you suggesting me to do then? i need to create a thread from a dll file..

Comment: Dan, do you own the source of the application into which this DLL is loaded?

Comment: Yes i am loading the dll using LoadLibary function..  LoadLibrary(L"alpha.dll") don't get me wrong. it does load the dll when i remove the "if (DllThread == NULL)" a messagebox is poped up the problem is that the thread is not working

Comment: You need to export a method that starts your thread, so the host EXE can decide when (and whether) to call it. Keep in mind that just because your DLL is being *loaded* doesn't mean the host app actually intends to *run* your code -- it might be Explorer trying to load an icon resource, and your thread could crash the whole desktop. (Or lock it up, if you're trying to create your thread from DllMain.)

Comment: It is not allowed to call LoadLibrary() or FreeLibrary() from the DLL entry point/ startup code. Windows may get confused and Load or Free DLLs in the wrong order. Creating a thread in DllMain() is tricky because the system may have to call LoadLibrary() to do that. In general: don't do things in DllMain() that posibly can fail. Write an exported function to do the startup work instead, and call that function from the host application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of starting the thread from `DllMain()` export a function that would launch the thread instead:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void start_thread()
{
    DWORD DllThreadID;
    HANDLE DllThread; //thread's handle

    DllThread=CreateThread(NULL,0,ThreadProc,0,0,&DllThreadID);
    if (DllThread == NULL)
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error", L"Error", MB_OK);
    else
        CloseHandle(DllThread);

}
```

After calling `LoadLibrary()` use `GetProcAddress()` to get access to the `start_thread()` function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this is a very old thread, but it may shed some light on a problem I'm having...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49653102/threads-not-running-why?noredirect=1#comment86319707_49653102