# Threads not running, why?

Tags: c++, beginthread

I wrote a simple test application to prove that the threads work:

```
    // Test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"

    class clsTest {
    private:
        uintptr_t muintHandle;

        static unsigned int __stdcall fnThread(void* pData) {
            while( 1 ) {
                _sleep(1000);
                printf("In fnThread, handle = %d\n", *(uintptr_t*)pData);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    public:
        clsTest() {
            muintHandle = _beginthreadex(0, 0, &clsTest::fnThread, (void*)&muintHandle, 0, 0);
            printf("clsTest(), after beginthreadex, handle = %u\n", muintHandle);
        }
    };

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
        clsTest* pT = NULL;

        while(1) {
            printf("From _tmain\n");

            if ( pT == NULL ) {
                pT = new clsTest();
            }
            _sleep(1000);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The output from this application is:

```
    From _tmain
    clsTest(), after beginthreadex, handle = 112
    In fnThread, handle = 112
    From _tmain
    In fnThread, handle = 112
    From _tmain
    In fnThread, handle = 112
    From _tmain
    In fnThread, handle = 112
    From _tmain
    In fnThread, handle = 112
    From _tmain
    In fnThread, handle = 112        
    ...
```

Continuously which is exactly what I would expect to see...Now in a much larger project I have a base class:

```
    typedef enum {
            eIdle = 0,      //Thread is not working at all
            eStarted,       //Thread has been started but is not fully operational yet
            eRunning,       //Thread is working normally
            ePausing,       //Thread is requested to enter the paused state
            ePaused,        //Thread is paused
            eTerminating    //Termination has been requested but not completed yet
        } eThreadStates; 

    class clsOpenLDVthread {
    protected:
        volatile eThreadStates meState;
        CRITICAL_SECTION mCritControl;  // critical section for thread control
        char mszName[80];
        HANDLE mhEvent, mhThread;
        virtual bool blnStart() = 0;

    public:
        clsOpenLDVthread(LPCSTR pszName);
        ~clsOpenLDVthread();

        bool inline blnIsRunning();
        bool inline blnIsStopped();
        bool inline blnIsStopping();
        bool inline blnIsStarting();
        bool inline blnIsPausing();
        bool inline blnIsPaused();
        bool blnPause(bool blnState);
        virtual bool blnStop();
    };

    clsOpenLDVthread::clsOpenLDVthread(LPCSTR pszName) : meState(eIdle)
                                               , mhThread(NULL) {
        ::InitializeCriticalSection(&mCritControl); //Get a critical section
        //Get a unique name for signaling event
        sprintf(mszName, "%s%d", pszName, ::GetCurrentProcessId());
        //Get the event object
        mhEvent = ::CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, mszName);
    }       
    clsOpenLDVthread::~clsOpenLDVthread() {
        if ( blnIsPaused() ) {
            blnPause(false);
        }
        if ( blnIsRunning() ) {
            blnStop();
        }
        if ( mhEvent ) {
            ::CloseHandle(mhEvent);
            mhEvent = NULL;
        }
        ::DeleteCriticalSection(&mCritControl);
    }
    bool clsOpenLDVthread::blnIsPaused() {
        return meState == ePaused;
    }
    bool clsOpenLDVthread::blnIsPausing() {
        return meState == ePausing;
    }
    bool clsOpenLDVthread::blnIsRunning() {
        return meState == eRunning;
    }
    bool clsOpenLDVthread::blnIsStarting() {
        return meState == eStarted;
    }
    bool clsOpenLDVthread::blnIsStopped() {
        return meState == eIdle;
    }
    bool clsOpenLDVthread::blnIsStopping() {
        return meState == eTerminating;
    }
    bool clsOpenLDVthread::blnPause(bool blnState) {
        bool blnResult = mhThread != NULL;
        if ( blnResult ) {
            if ( blnState ) {
                unsigned uintCountDown = 10u;

                if ( blnIsRunning() || blnIsPausing() ) {
                    meState = ePausing;
                    while( blnIsPausing() && -- uintCountDown ) {
                        ::SetEvent(mhEvent);
        //Give thread chance to run and pause
                        _sleep(751);
                    }
                    blnResult = blnIsPaused();
                }
            } else {
                if ( blnIsPaused() ) {
                    meState = eRunning;
                    //this will need replacing...mhThread->ResumeThread();
                }
                blnResult = true;
            }
        }
        return blnResult;
    }
    bool clsOpenLDVthread::blnStop() {
        bool blnResult = meState == eIdle;
        unsigned uintCountDown = 100u;

        if ( blnIsPaused() ) {
            blnPause(false);
        }
        if ( blnIsRunning() ) {
            meState = eTerminating;

            while( !blnIsStopped() && --uintCountDown ) {
                if ( mhEvent ) {
                    ::SetEvent(mhEvent);
                }
        //Give thread a change to run and terminate
                _sleep(501);
            }
            blnResult = blnIsStopped();
            mhThread = NULL;
        }
        return blnResult;
    }
```

Finally a derived class that implements the thread class and provides the blnStart method:

```
    class clsOpenLDVrdr : public clsOpenLDVthread {
    public:
    //Maximum size of uplink data per single transfer
        static const unsigned mscuBuffersize;
    private:
    //The thread's main routine
        static void msgReaderThread(LPVOID lpParam);

    public:
        clsOpenLDVrdr();
        virtual ~clsOpenLDVrdr();
    //Call this to start the thread, see clsOpenLDVthread for more operations
        virtual bool blnStart();
    };

    const unsigned clsOpenLDVrdr::mscuBuffersize = MAX_OPENLDV_DATA;

    clsOpenLDVrdr::clsOpenLDVrdr() : clsOpenLDVthread(_T("EvOpenLDVrdr")) {
    }
    clsOpenLDVrdr::~clsOpenLDVrdr() {
    }
    bool clsOpenLDVrdr::blnStart() {
        bool blnResult = false;
        if ( blnIsStopped() ) {
            meState = eStarted;
        //Create the thread
            mhThread = (HANDLE)_beginthread(&clsOpenLDVrdr::msgReaderThread
                                            ,0, NULL);
            blnResult = mhThread != NULL;

            while( blnResult && (meState == eStarted) ) {
        //Give the thread chance to start and initialize
                _sleep(501);
            }
        }
        return blnResult && (meState == eRunning);
    }
    void clsOpenLDVrdr::msgReaderThread(LPVOID lpParam) {
            OutputDebugString("msgReaderThread\n");
    }
```

An instance of the class clsOpenLDVrdr is created and the blnStart method called:

```
    clsOpenLDVrdr* pobjReader = new clsOpenLDVrdr();
    pobjReader->blnStart();
```

I can see in the debugger that "blnStart" is being called and stepping into it everything is executed...but the thread never runs.

Also tried using _beginthreadex instead of _beginthread:

```
    mhThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, pfnThread, pobParam, 0, 0);
```

No difference.  There is some kind of incompatibility problem here as the simple example I created at the start of this post works and there isn't much difference between the two versions.  Except maybe the way its used...the first simple example was created as a Windows console application.  The project I'm having difficulty with is in a DLL.

I'm attaching to the DLL with the debugger and stepping through the code which works until it gets to the loop after the beginthread call then it just loops forever and never gets into the thread.

I just tried the following, adding a standalone thread with a standard C function:

```
    unsigned __stdcall threadTest(void* pobjData) {
        OutputDebugString("threadTest\n");
        return 0;
   }
```

I then modify the "_beginthread" call as follows:

```
    mhThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, threadTest, pobjParam, 0, 0);
```

Sadly the result is the same, the threadTest function is not called.  But a valid handle is returned.

Found this:

[unable to call a thread in dll file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274083/unable-to-call-a-thread-in-dll-file)

Looks interesting and may explain the strange behaviour I'm experiencing.

Comment: You may be interested the c++ standard library's [thread support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Comment: Does the thread never run? Or does the main thread ask the thread's state (e.g. with `blnIsRunning()`) and never receives `true`? If thread is updating `mestate` and `clsOpenLDVthread::blnIsRunning()` (called from main thread) accesses `mestate` it has to be safed by a mutex or made `atomic`. Otherwise, "internal magic" (e.g. caching) may prevent that both threads get equal/correct results (at the same time).

Comment: In the thread function I am sending a message to the console, it never gets executed.  See the first very simple example which works...the later doesn't.

Comment: Nevertheless, _every_ data which is shared between threads must be safed against concurrent access. I once was thinking a `bool` (in my imagination a bit) is atomic by definition. Until I learnt that I was wrong. Caching, code re-ordering and such things can make this assumption wrong. The only chance to grant correct behavior (i.e. force determinism) is to insert fences and barriers by using locks or atomics.

Comment: @Scheff, I understand what you are saying and I have used mutexes before to lock and unlock and protect data areas...however this is a stage I will implement later, at the moment it is not getting to the thread itself, in my thread handler there is no shared data just an output to the console...it never gets there.

Comment: After looking again, I'm not quite sure. The thread should at least start one time. (Couldn't see anything suspicious.) The only thing where I'm not sure about: `OutputDebugString("msgReaderThread\n");` (I've never used it. May be, you've experiences with it but not if called in another thread than the main thread...) Did you set a break point on it which was reached in debugger? (Replacement with `printf()` as in your first test would do as well.)

Comment: @Scheff,  I added that line just to see that something was going to be output to the console...the function OutputDebugString is ok it works in Windows and outputs to the console, but setting a break point on this line or even a simple variable assignment in the thread body, never gets executed.

Comment: Btw. If `clsOpenLDVrdr::msgReaderThread()` is the thread main function it stops very soon. Make a loop with a sleep into it as you did in your test. (Not that it exits too soon...) ;-) (Although, it does not explain why the breakpoint is never reached...)

Comment: @Scheff, yet msgReaderThread is the thread body function, the intention in the final code is to add a lot more to it, but it never gets there even once, which it should...

Comment: so what's `blnResult`?

Comment: @UKMonkey, its a boolean variable, true or false.

Comment: @SPlatten very funny :P   What's it's value.  Does the OS report that it's started a thread?

Comment: @UkMonkey, sorry, wasn't trying to be funny, I didn't know what you were asking, isn't the result obvious?  If mhThread (the handle) returned is not NULL or 0 then the result is true else false.

Comment: I've also just tried using _beginthreadex, will edit post now to show with alternative, but the result is the same...

Comment: @SPlatten yes it it obvious - but you've not said if it's true or false.  ie are you trying to work out why a thread doesn't enter it's main because the OS never reports that it's started a thread...

Comment: @UKMonkey, the result of blnResult is true a typical value of 'mhThread ' is 0x00000794

Comment: @SPlatten Which suggests the _thread_ is being created, but that something happens to it before it gets to your `OutputDebugString()` call. Not overly experienced in threads, but can you pass a class-member function to `_beginthread()`? (It's probably expecting a `this` and not getting anything). Try just passing a standalone function at first. Then, as in your first example, try a `static` member function. If you _need_ a class-memeber function, you will probably need to pass `this` in to `_beginthread()` as morph it back into a class-pointer in the thread function.

Comment: @TripeHound, Please see edit of my post at the bottom, I will add my results now.

Comment: What is the threading model of your linked c runtime library?  Assuming it's /MT

Comment: @JoshGreifer, sorry, I'm not sure what you mean, how do I find out?

Comment: Are you using visual studio to build your application?

Comment: @JoshGreifer, yes, Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, version 9.0.30729 SP

Comment: Well,  I can't remember where the option is in VS 2008, but in later versions you'll find it in the "C/C++ -> Code Generation" section of the project properties.  Should be set to /MT or /MTd

Comment: @JoshGreifer, in C/C++ Code Generation, Runtime Library, "Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168238/discussion-between-josh-greifer-and-splatten).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved...I didn't realise at first but for some reason the existing DLL had a call to:

```
    DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hInstance);
```

This prevents the threads from running.  Having commented this out everything now works.